# Recording gaps between two times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Below given, is a set of data from one of the tables I have, Is there any way to track the empty time? (e.g  (11:00-12:00) and (18:45-19:15) as gap for that date).

```
       Date           Activity  From     To    Duration
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    08:00   11:00   3.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Travel  12:00   13:00   1.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    13:00   15:00   2.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    15:00   18:00   3.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Travel  18:00   18:45   0.75
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    19:15   22:15   3.00
```

I'm expecting something like below

```
       Date           Activity  From     To    Duration
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    08:00   11:00   3.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Gap     11:00   12:00   1.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Travel  12:00   13:00   1.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    13:00   15:00   2.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    15:00   18:00   3.00
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Travel  18:00   18:45   0.75
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Gap     18:45   19:15   0.50
2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 Work    19:15   22:15   3.00
```

Can this be done without looping? If so,? how can it be done?

Comment: Please read this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-main&utm_content=sqlgapsandislands-20130805&utm_campaign=sql). Alex

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: @techdo : Please find the revised question above

Comment: What is the datatype of From and To columns?

Comment: You can use an approach like this:
   SELECT ID, StartSeqNo=SeqNo + 1, EndSeqNo=(
    SELECT MIN(B.SeqNo)
       FROM dbo.GapsIslands AS B
       WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.SeqNo > A.SeqNo) - 1
   FROM dbo.GapsIslands AS A
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.GapsIslands AS B
   WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND B.SeqNo = A.SeqNo + 1) AND
    SeqNo < (SELECT MAX(SeqNo)
   FROM dbo.GapsIslands B
    WHERE B.ID = A.ID);
,from the link below

Comment: @techdo : they are of varchar(5). 24hr timing in HH:MM format

Comment: @GatejAlexandru : Thanks. Its very informative. But in the current context, From and To are 24hr timing in HH:MM format.

Comment: You can try to use datetime for sql2005 like this, SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '08:00:00'), or you can construct with your date column, because I have the impression that you need to calculate this gaps for multiple days, and afterwards apply the principle describe in the algorithm from article. The difference will be that you apply on dates not numbers. For sql2008 and above you can use the Time datatype directly(i didn't used it before but it should work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is `DUARTION` an INT type?
The following query unions original table with the query which outputs GAPS then order this UNION by `Date` and `From`

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76e12/12)

```
SELECT 
Date,
Activity,
[FROM],
[TO],
CONVERT(varchar(5),
CONVERT(Datetime,[TO],108)-
CONVERT(Datetime,[FROM],108)
,108) as Duration


 FROM
(
select Date,Activity,[From],[To] from T
UNION ALL
select Date,'GAP' as Activity, [To] as [From],
(select TOP 1 T.[From] from T where T.Date=T1.Date
                          and T.[From]>T1.[To] 
                          order by T.[From])
as [To]


from T as T1
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from T where T.Date=T1.Date 
                                    and T.[From]=T1.[To]) 
      and EXISTS (select 1 from T where T.Date=T1.Date 
                                    and T.[From]>T1.[To])  

) T2
ORDER BY Date,[FROM]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
    [Date],
    Activity,
    [From],
    [To],
    CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(Datetime,[TO])-CONVERT(Datetime,[FROM]), 108) Duration
From
(
    select 
        [Date],
        'Gap' Activity,
        [To] [From],
        (select top 1 d.[From] from YourTable d where CONVERT(datetime, d.[Date]+d.[From])>CONVERT(datetime, a.[Date]+a.[To]) order by CONVERT(datetime, d.[Date]+d.[From])) as [To],
        NULL as Duration
    from YourTable a
    where 
        (select COUNT(*) from YourTable b where CONVERT(datetime, b.[Date]+b.[From])=CONVERT(datetime, a.[Date]+a.[To]))=0

    union all

    select * From YourTable
)x 
where 
    [To] IS NOT NULL
order by CONVERT(datetime, x.[Date]+x.[From])
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. But, It will surely hit performance when the table has large set of data. Any easy shot ?